# Using Trace tool with BMP file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, trace

I am digitizing a map 
using ArcGIS 10.

When I use trace is there any way to trace black lines from a BMP file?

Comment: no image added sorry its not working

Comment: How does the BMP file fit in with tracing lines? Please give more details on exactly what your question is. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [Trace](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000032000000.htm) tool will only "follow the shapes of other [vector] features", not raster (imagery, like a BMP).

I think what you are really looking for is something like the [ArcScan](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000w00000001000000.htm) extension, which "allow[s] you to convert scanned images into vector-based feature layers."  In particular, see the subsection titled "**Interactive vectorization (raster tracing)**".

Answer (score 1):

If the image is not too complex, you could use the [Raster to Polyline](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000) or Polygon conversion tools to create the vector data, then trace those features.

If the image is fairly simple it should get you close, you may need to play with the [smooth line tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Smooth_Line/007000000012000000/) to get the conversion output closer.

If your image is very complex you may want to think about using an image editing tool(IrfanView, GIMP, Photoshop) to simplify down to the black lines you were referring to before converting to polylines.